# Copy to Clipboard JS function causing keyboard to open and scroll to top on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my rails app, I have an event listener on a "copy to clipboard" icon. When that's clicked, I call a function which creates a textarea, selects it, and copies it using document.execCommand("copy").

Everything works great on desktop, but on mobile - clicking the icon scrolls to the top of the page and opens the keyboard.

How do I avoid this?

```
  // copies shareable url

  $('body').on('click', '.clipboard', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).closest('.trailer').find('.shareable-url')
    copyToClipboard(url)
  });


//  copy to Clipboard

function copyToClipboard(elem) {

    // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.val();
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    var x = window.scrollX, y = window.scrollY;
    target.focus();
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
        succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
```